# Update ember data store after successful ajax POST

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to access ember data store after a successful ajax request. Here is what I'm trying:

```
$.ajax({
   contentType: "application/json",
   method: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   processData: false,
   url: url,
   success: this.actions.update,
   beforeSend: function() {
   },
   error: function() {
   }
});


update(data) {
  this.get('store').pushPayload({
    item: {
      id: data.item.id,
      title: data.item.title,
      images: data.images
    }
  });
},
```

The problem here is that `this` is not the ember component rather it is the ajax object. I need to be able to access ember so that I can update the store. So, this needs to work `this.get('store')` Does anybody know how to achieve this or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either bind this to your function (my preferred way of handling these kinds of situations) or use closure to share `this.get('store')` in both places.

**binding**

```
...
success: this.actions.update.bind(this)
....
```

**closure**

```
const store = this.get('store');
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: update
});

// Note this isn't an action anymore, but a declared function
function update() {
  ...
}
```

You could also use **ES6 arrow functions**, which maintain the context of this

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: data => {
  }
  ...
});
```

As an aside, I would seriously consider ditching the `success` and `error` properties in the `$.ajax` call - it returns a promise which you can chain `.then` on. You still need to either bind `this`, use closure or use an arrow function, but there are benefits to moving toward using promises rather than callbacks.

**Using a Promise**

```
$.ajax({...}).then(
  successFunction,
  errorFunction
);
```